# MySQL performance of query making addition of columns in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sqlperformance

I have a query making an addition of several column values in the `WHERE` clause. I can't precompute this addition in a single column because the combination of columns to use varies between queries. My problem is that my table is very large (several hundreds of millions of rows) and the performances very bad.

Example table:

```
+---------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| tableId | categoryId | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
+---------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1 |          1 |      1 |      0 |      5 |      7 |
|       2 |          1 |      8 |      1 |      7 |      0 |
|       3 |          1 |     10 |      5 |      0 |     20 |
|       4 |          2 |      0 |     15 |      0 |     22 |
|       5 |          2 |     20 |      0 |     11 |      0 |
+---------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Example queries:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE categoryId = 1 AND (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4) > 9;
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE categoryId = 1 AND (value1 + value3 + value4) > 5;
```

What would be the best strategy for improving performances of such queries? (edit: I already have an index on `categoryId`, this does not help)

Does using an index help for such queries? Would I then have to create all possible indexes for all possible combinations of columns? Wouldn't the resulting indexes be very very large?

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value1),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value2),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value3),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value4),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value1, value2),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value1, value3),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value1, value4),
etc
```

Or maybe creating a link table, with boolean value fields specifying which columns were used? But that would result in a table with several billions rows, not sure this is better...

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| tableId | useValue1 | useValue2 | useValue3 | useValue4 | valueSum |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |       13 |
|       1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         0 |        6 |
|       1 |         1 |         1 |         0 |         0 |        1 |
|       1 |         1 |         1 |         0 |         1 |        8 |
|       1 |         1 |         0 |         1 |         1 |       13 |
|       1 |         1 |         0 |         1 |         0 |        6 |
|       1 |         1 |         0 |         0 |         0 |        1 |
|       1 |         1 |         0 |         0 |         1 |        8 |
|       1 |         0 |         1 |         1 |         1 |       12 |
|       1 |         0 |         1 |         1 |         0 |        5 |
|       1 |         0 |         1 |         0 |         0 |        0 |
|       1 |         0 |         1 |         0 |         1 |        7 |
|       1 |         0 |         0 |         1 |         1 |       12 |
|       1 |         0 |         0 |         1 |         0 |        5 |
|       1 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         1 |        7 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

With an Index:

```
ALTER TABLE linkTable INDEX(tableId, useValue1, useValue2, useValue3, useValue4, valueSum);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: How can anyone figure that out without what your data actually is!!!!

Comment: @e4c5: I agree and I could make another post questioning the entire worflow, computations, outputs and storage. But this is what I have to deal with as of today :) What do you think of my second idea?

Comment: Enumerated columns are symptomatic of poor design- which in turn can affect performance

Comment: Maybe try column store engine for MySQL? Like ICE or InfiniDB. You wouldn't need indexes, because they store data similar to row-based storage indexes. This type of storage works faster for certain use cases, while slower for others.

Comment: @e4c5: OK, following your remarks I describe my actual problem in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42781299/1768736

Comment: @Strawberry: OK, following your remark I describe my actual problem in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42781299/1768736

Answer (score 0):

@e4c5 is right that none of the indices will help with the current query. You can start by adding the following indices and alter the query with additional conditions so that the indices get used:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value1),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value2),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value3),
ADD INDEX(categoryId, value4);
```

And update the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE categoryId = 1 AND (value1 <= 9) AND (value2 <= 9) AND (value3 <= 9) AND (value4 <= 9) AND (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4) > 9;
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE categoryId = 1 AND (value1 <= 5) AND (value3 <= 5) AND (value4 <= 5) AND (value1 + value3 + value4) > 5;
```

The additional conditions helps to narrow down the number of rows to be processed. Adding indices on more columns would speed this up further but I suggest trying this first.

Comment: Mysql uses only one index per table

Comment: yes it does @ec45. The additional condition above should use the index which involves the least number of rows

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to make some guesses until I see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`...

If you have this:

```
tableId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
categoryId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY(tableId),
```

Then change to

```
tableId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,  -- same
categoryId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,              -- same
...
PRIMARY KEY(categoryId, tableId),  -- different, see Note 1
INDEX(tableId)                     -- different, see Note 2
```

Note 1. The index (the PK) starting with `categoryId` will help the queries you presented.  Furthermore, by being at the beginning of the PK, it will "cluster" all the necessary rows for one `SELECT` together, thereby minimizing the I/O in your huge table.

Note 2. Yes, it is OK to have only `INDEX(...)` for the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Another tip...  Since `BIGINT` is always 8 bytes and `INT` is 4 bytes; do you really need that big a column?  Shrinking the columns sizes will help cut down on I/O, which will significantly speed up the queries.  `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` is only 3 bytes and has a range of 0..16M; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers in [my follow-up question about the overall database design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781299/1768736), the conclusions are:

- All my data types and indexes are correct.
- My design with enumerated columns is not very elegant, but adapted to a row-based database such as MySQL and gives the best performances on that kind of engine.
- To really fix this performance issue, I should move to a column-based database, using a better design as described in comments of my other question (where data to aggregate would be in a same column but several rows).

Answer (score -1):

You can put your queries into categories. For each category, you can keep a column which are pre-computed. You can SELECT the related field from the table with respect to required combination of calculations. Of course it is possible if you can categorize your queries.

Comment: This would make 15 combinations as of today, more in the future. I was trying to avoid such a design :/