# Alternative to database design with enumerated columns, leading to poor performances

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Following remarks on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42779175/1768736), I describe here the problem that led me to have a database schema with enumerated columns, leading to poor performances.

**(see edit at the bottom of this question for my overall conclusion)**

I work with gene expression data. We capture in which `condition`s any `gene` is expressed (for instance, to say that gene X is expressed in the condition[organ Y - life stage Z]). I have 4 `dataType`s that can produce such expression data. So my raw data are stored in different tables, for instance (this is just an illustrative example, the raw data are far more complex):

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| Field              | Type                               | Null | Key | Default      | Extra |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
| geneId             | int(10) unsigned                   | NO   | PRI | NULL         |       |
| evidenceId         | varchar(70)                        | NO   | PRI | NULL         |       |
| experimentId       | varchar(70)                        | NO   | MUL | NULL         |       |
| conditionId        | mediumint(8) unsigned              | NO   | MUL | NULL         |       |
| expressionId       | int(10) unsigned                   | NO   | MUL | NULL         |       |
| detectionFlag      | enum('expressed', 'not expressed') | NO   |     | NULL         |       |
| quality            | enum('low quality','high quality') | NO   |     | NULL         |       |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------+-------+
```

I have one such table per `dataType`. Now, typical queries will request thousands of genes at a same time. Because the data are very large (several hundreds of millions of rows in each table), and includes redundant values (tons of evidence for a same `gene`, tons of `gene`s for a same evidence), it is very slow to query each table individually. For this reason, we have a precomputed "summary" table, computed from the information in these 4 tables:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| expressionId   | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| geneId         | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conditionId    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

(Note that there are other useful columns in this table). The `expressionId` field allows to get back to the raw data.

Now my problem is:

- for each data type, we compute a `summaryQuality`, based on the number of distinct experiments supporting an expression row, in the `condition` itself, but also taking into account any related `condition` (I let out what is a related `condition`, but, yes, relations between `condition`s could be stored in another table).
- Users should be able to compute a "global" `summaryQuality`, by summing experiments supporting an expression row for any combination of `dataType`s. E.g., they should be able to say "give me results supported by x experiments from the sum of experiments in dataType1 and dataType2", or "give me results supported by y experiments from the sum of experiments in dataType1 and dataType2 and dataType3 and dataType4".

So I ended up with the following design:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| expressionId             | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| geneId                   | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conditionId              | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dataType1ExperimentCount | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| dataType2ExperimentCount | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| dataType3ExperimentCount | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| dataType4ExperimentCount | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Rows in this table are precomputed by taking into account all `dataType`s and all related `condition`s of a given `conditionId`. This is very slow to compute. The table has hundreds of millions of rows as a result.

Now my queries look like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE geneId IN (?, ?, ?, ...) AND (dataType1ExperimentCount + dataType2ExperimentCount + dataType3ExperimentCount + dataType4ExperimentCount) >= ?;
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE geneId IN (?, ?, ?, ...) AND (dataType1ExperimentCount + dataType2ExperimentCount) >= ?;
```

The performances are very bad, because such queries can't use indexes, according to answers in my previous question. I need to allow any combination of `dataType`s. I need to allow addition of new `dataType`s in the future (thus making the number of combinations reaching 32 or 64 very fast).

What better design could I come up with?

Edit following request of user Rick James, the show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `expression` (
  `expressionId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `geneId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `conditionId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dataType1ExperimentCount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dataType2ExperimentCount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dataType3ExperimentCount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dataType4ExperimentCount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`expressionId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `geneId` (`geneId`,`conditionId`),
  KEY `conditionId` (`conditionId`),
  CONSTRAINT `expression_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`geneId`) REFERENCES `gene` (`geneId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `expression_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`conditionId`) REFERENCES `cond` (`conditionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(and, yes, a given `geneId` has less rows in table than a given `conditionId`, so the multiple unique key is properly ordered).

**Edit, overall conclusion**:

- @RickJame's answer made my queries run 4 to 5 times faster, they now run in a reasonable time. Problem solved for now.
- But @Strawberry is right that my design could be improved (see comments of this question)
- But on MySQL, the "correct" design makes my queries run 10 times slower. I think this is because MySQL is a row-based database, well adapted at retrieving all information in multiple columns on a single row, as in my current "enumerated" design.
- I think that the long term solution would be to switch to a column-based database, as proposed in @ŁukaszKamiński's answer, using the correct design proposed by @Strawberry. Because then, the information to retrieve would be in several rows, but a same column.

Comment: I suspect this question would be a better fit for Software Engineering or DB Admin. Are you sure a RDBMS is a good platform for this kind of work, though?

Comment: Does "mytable" have any indexes? Can you show an EXPLAIN?

Comment: As before, enumerated columns are symptomatic of poor design - which in turn can affect performance. Expression, gene, and condition belong in a separate table to "datatypes" and experiment counts. But both should be linked by a common id.

Comment: @Strawberry: OK, let's admit that I move each datatype experiment count in a separate table. How will that fix my performance issue when the query will look like: `SELECT myTable.* FROM myTable LEFT OUTER JOIN dataType1 ON myTable.expressionId = dataType1.expressionId LEFT OUTER JOIN ... (for each data type) WHERE geneId IN (?, ?, ?, ...) AND (IFNULL(dataType1.experimentCount, 0) + IFNULL(dataType2.experimentCount, 0) + IFNULL(dataType3.experimentCount, 0) + IFNULL(dataType4.experimentCount, 0)) >= ?;`. I don't think it will help.

Comment: You're not going to have 4 datatype columns. You will have one column which contains the data type sequence id (1-4), one column which holds the count for that id, and one column which holds the FK to the gene_expression table.

Comment: @Strawberry: so are you suggesting that my queries would end up looking like: `SELECT myTable.*, SUM(expCount) AS expCountSum FROM myTable INNER JOIN expCount ON myTable.expressionId = expCount.expressionId WHERE myTable.geneId IN (?, ?, ?, ...) AND expCount.dataType IN (?, ?, ?, ?) GROUP BY myTable.expressionId HAVING expCountSum >= ?`. Do you think the use of a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause would make it worth it?

Comment: This is the correct way to store data.

Comment: @LSerni when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @Strawberry: I'm going to generate the table you suggest today. I agree that it is a far cleaner design. Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it/comment it after testing it.

Comment: Calculate (estimate) the size of the table. Does it fit into memory? Given that you can not use indexes it probably scanning the whole table. The "latency gap" (access time) between disk and memory is about 4-5 orders of magnitude, so  having it in memory will help. Otherwise consider exporting to in-memory-cluster platform that allows parallel execution -- say Spark.

Comment: I'm confused -- you describe a many:many mapping between genes and evidences, yet show a table with expressionid and gene and condition.  If that is a many:many mapping table, then follow [_my 7 many:many tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).  (You are already following some, but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` is the important part.)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; `DESCRIBE` is less descriptive.  In particular, we need to see the indexes.

Comment: Is gene + condition "unique" in your unnamed schema?

Comment: @Strawberry: I tested your solution, and the performances are twice worse than with my enumerated design. But I agree that your design is the correct one. Thus I should move to a column-based engine to implement it with good performances (see my comment on Lukasz's answer).

Comment: @RickJames: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` added at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
PRIMARY KEY (`expressionId`),
UNIQUE KEY `geneId` (`geneId`,`conditionId`),
```

use

```
PRIMARY KEY(`geneId`,`conditionId`),
INDEX (`expressionId`),
```

If no other tables are refencing `expressionId`, get rid of that column and the index on it.

Why does this help?  The data is clustered with the Primary key; you are looking up data by `geneId`, which is the start of the PK; hence the data can be fetched more efficiently, especially if the table is a lot bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (which should be about 70% of RAM).

Comment: Isn't it the case with a `UNIQUE KEY` as well? Would you have a link to an official documentation mentioning this difference? edit: [found it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html). This is very interesting, thank you, I'm going to try and accept your answer if it works (but answer from Lukasz is also good :/)

Comment: @FBB - Saying `PRIMARY` makes it clustered, which is an important factor in my Answer.  A `UNIQUE` key _may_ be turned into `PRIMARY`; I don't want to depend on that.

Comment: Amazing, my query now runs 4 to 5 times faster using a clustered index. Thanks a lot!

Comment: 4x-5x -- Probably your table is too big to be cached.  Clustering (where practical) cuts back significantly on the amount of I/O.  Hence, I went out of my way to get `geneId` at the beginning of your PK.

Answer (score 1):

From previous post:

Maybe try column store engine for MySQL? Like ICE or InfiniDB. You wouldn't need indexes, because they store data similar to row-based storage indexes. This type of storage works faster for certain use cases, while slower for others. Data warehouses, aggregates, analytic queries and such should benefit.

There are community versions as well as paid enterprise editions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how these store engines would manage my problem better, with an example maybe?

Comment: Assuming you don't actually need to `SELECT *`, but only a few columns from row, then it will have less IO and as a result take less time to get the data. It also scales much better and the more columns you have the better.
It could also save some space by compressing data in similar fashion column index uses compression.

You can see some benchmark and better explanation of column store engines/databases here: https://reportserver.net/blog/2016/06/20/mariadb-columnstore-vs-innodb-vs-monetdb/

Comment: Your answer is actually the correct one, following tests based on comments from user @Strawberry: with the "correct" design, the data to aggregate will be on a same column in several rows, well adapted to a column-based database. With my current "bad" enumerated design, all information is on a same row in different columns, well adapted to row-based database such as InnoDB. Performances using InnoDB are twice better with my enumerated design rather than with the "correct" design. The correct design thus implies to move to a column-based solution for good performances.

Comment: If the data is loaded into the table mostly in `geneId` order, InfiniDB (available as an Engine in newer MariaDB versions) will shine.  Otherwise, it will probably be slow due to having to uncompress virtually everything for the queries in question.  (I don't know ICE.)

Comment: @RickJames: insertion order has an impact on `SELECT` performances with these engines? Isn't it weird?

Comment: @FBB - Some Engines (MyISAM and InfiniDB) work that way.  Some don't -- InnoDB is ordered by the explicit `PRIMARY KEY`, if you specify one.

Comment: So, I accepted @RickJames 's answer instead, because while your solution might solve my issue in the long term, Rick Jame's solution provides me with an immediate solution.